# Writing script that will merge shapefiles?

Tags: shapefile, intramaps-roam

We use an application called IntraMaps Roam.  Our guys go out in the field, mark up their maps with GPS points, and then bring them back to the office.  They will copy their shapefiles to the server and the script will combine them at night.  The next morning they will download the new maps.

How can I accomplish this task?

Comment: Combine the GPS points from various collectors into a single shapefile?

Comment: http://www.vdstech.com/geomerge.aspx merges shapefiles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you use GDAL?

The first step would to be create an output `merge.shp` file, so file1 you would do:

```
ogr2ogr -f ‘ESRI Shapefile’ merge.shp filename1.shp
```

Then update that `merge.shp` file with the other files:

```
ogr2ogr -f ‘ESRI Shapefile’ -update -append merge.shp filename2.shp -nln merge
```

You would loop that last command for each of the files that are needed. The example in the source is bash, but this can easily be turned into a powershell script.

source: http://www.northrivergeographic.com/ogr2ogr-merge-shapefiles